# Moving SharePoint App Catalog to a different domain

Tags: sharepoint-online, move, app-catalog

We have an app that gives out error:

> ([SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]: Failed to load component because it doesn't reside in the same domain as the app catalog.

Is there a way to move the catalog without having to delete and create a new one?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Essentialy change the App Catlog form
https:/MySite-OldDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/apps
To:
https:/MySite-O365.sharepoint.com/sites/apps

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you can move app catalog to another tenant since app catalog is highly scope strict.

Even if you managed to move the App Catalog site collection to the new location, it is most likely not to take effect in the new tenant.

If the issue happens to a single app, I suggest you remove the app and add it directly to the app catalog site collection in another tenant.

References:

[Use the App Catalog to make custom business apps available for your SharePoint Online environment.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/use-app-catalog)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm planning to do.